# Send Dialog return success or fail

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i would like know how can i get the response after i sent the private message by send dialog of facebook.

example:

```
      FB.ui({
          app_id:"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          method: 'send',
          name: "Test send message",
          link: 'www.mywebsite.gi',
          to: ID_USER_FB,
          description:'This is a test '

      });
      // here i would a response
      if (response == TRUE) {
         // do this
      } else {
        // do that
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The FB.ui method takes two parameters:  a data object and a callback function as documented here: [FB.ui](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)

The callback function would be something like this:

```
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
   }
```

The important thing to note is that the FB.ui method is asynchronous,  that is why it requires the callback method.